# Different installed app size on different devices

Tags: android

My app apk file size is about 25 MB. When I install it (debug or release version) on my Sony Xperia (Android 4.0.4), application size is about 30 MB. But some users complain, that installed app size is about 80 MB, for example on Galaxy Ace 2 device (Android 4.x). It is application size right after installation.

How can installed application size differ more than 2 times on different devices?

I use Android SDK Tools Rev. 22.3; SDK Build-tools 18.0.1.

Comment: Are you sure those users are not using ART runtime ? That might be the cause. http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/art.html

Comment: @MadhurAhuja, ART runtime was introduced in 4.4 release. But this problem appears on device with Android 4.2.1 too.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your development environment, and the settings you choose, you probably are using what's called "Multiple APK Support".

Pretty much you can optimize your app for different devices. Some people do this manually by testing on a bunch of different emulators, but there are also settings you can toggle to automatically do some optimizations for you. Even if you didn't do it intentionally, you're likely using some kind of Multiple APK application settings.

You can read more about Multiple APK Support here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html