# App installed size is different on different devices Android

Tags: android, installation, storage

My app is a background service without any GUI. Apk size is about 9 MB. When I installed this app on Samsung Note II(OS 4.4.2), application size is 18.55 MB, on Samsung Galaxy S4 37 MB and on Samsung Galaxy S5 69.47 MB.

I already found a similar question but no solution at: [Different installed app size on different devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695808/different-installed-app-size-on-different-devices)

Thanks for prompt response.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try with **[android:installLocation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install)**

> The application may be installed on the external storage, but the
>   system will install the application on the internal storage by
>   default. If the internal storage is full, then the system will install
>   it on the external storage. Once installed, the user can move the
>   application to either internal or external storage through the system
>   settings.

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

**FYI**

> The Google play store main application (APK) size, not the total app
>   size, which includes the OBB (Opaque Binary Blob) expansion files.
>   OBBs are the extra files that an app downloads to run.

Comment: android:installLocation="internalOnly" it's requirement to install this app on internal storage. I am curious about why application size differs on different devices?