# Android App size varies a lot with different devices?

Tags: android

I build my app and installed the same apk on 5 android devices. The apk is 3MB big, but the size when installed varies a lot from device to device. I want to know why that is and how I can counter that.

Comment: please give details about the size on each device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App installed size is different on different devices Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459313/app-installed-size-is-different-on-different-devices-android)